# Is my implementation comparable/related to (state) monads?

Tags: swift, functional-programming, monads

Prologue:

I dabbled with Haskell for a bit a few years ago reading through "[LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)" up to a certain point; and together with having used *Mathematica* for a bit, I'd say I have a grasp (more or less) of *some* of the fundamental ideas of functional programming, such as immutability, functional composition, currying, maps, folds, lazy evaluation, etc.

I think the last thing I read about from LYAH was functors (my memory of which is hazy) meaning I stopped somewhat short of the "dreaded" monad (not due to some irrational fear of them, rather I couldn't keep up my study of Haskell back then due to any of a number of reasons.) I've caught stray mention of monads here and there, but my idea of them is fairly fuzzy.

Now I'm playing around with Swift which has some support for functional paradigms. **My main question is to know how my solution to the problem specified below is related to monads (if at all).** If nothing else, it might give me the impetus to get back into studying pure functional programming with Haskell.

---

So this is the problem in its general form: I have a bunch of functions of type `T -> T`, and I'd like to be able to "chain" them in such a way that when I apply an argument of type `T`, not only do I get the back the value corresponding to the composition of these functions on the argument, but also the sequence of intermediate values (return value of each function in the sequence to which the return value of the previous function has been applied as the argument) in an array.

Now I know Swift has no qualms about modifying global variables from within functions (which could be used to store state), but I wanted to go about it in a functionally "purer" manner. My first thought was to modify my functions to have type `[T] -> [T]`, so that each function would take an array carrying all the previous state with it, and return an array with the return value tacked on at the end. But clearly this isn't a neat solution, and it obscures the fact that my functions' computations don't actually depend upon the past history of values.

So this is the solution I came up with:

```
infix operator << {
    associativity right
}


func wrap<T>(f: T -> T) -> (T -> (T, [T])) {
    return { x in       
        (f(x), [x]) }
}


func <<<T>(left: T -> T, right: T -> (T, [T])) -> T -> (T, [T]) {
    return { x in
        let r = right(x)
        let lr0 = left(r.0)
        return (lr0, r.1 + [r.0]) }
}

func <<<T>(left: T -> T, right: T -> T) -> T -> (T, [T]) {
    return left << wrap(right)
}

// Simple example; Int -> Int functions:
let addOne: Int -> Int = { x in x + 1 }
let mulTwo: Int -> Int = { x in 2 * x }
let subThree: Int -> Int = { x in x - 3 }

let seqOfOps = addOne << mulTwo << addOne << subThree
seqOfOps(10) // (.0 17, [10, 7, 8, 16]) // final value and history respectively
```

(I haven't taken the trouble to explain it as I expect people in a position to address my question should be able to follow along.)

So is my idea related to the monad concept, and if so how (and how not)? And if not, how would my solution be modified for a "proper" monadic solution?

I realise that by defining a `protocol` and employing type constraints I ought to be able to generalise the notion of "state", if that's one point of consideration.

Comment: I think this might actually be related to the [`Writer`](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#writer) monad. Its "classic" purpose is to aggregate intermediate stuff (like logging). The `<<` functions somehow look like Kleisli composition with pure functions.

Comment: "Kleisli composition" - cool name. I'll have to look it up.

Answer (score 1):

### Using monadic methods

It is related to the `Writer` type combined with the `State` type. This combination can be achieved through the use of the `WriterT` monad transformer.

`Writer` provides the accumulation of the result values and the `State` type provides access to the current value as we go along. The transformer allows us to use the methods associated with both types.

### An aside about monads

Actually, the weaker `Applicative` is *almost* strong enough to define all of this. We just need `Monad` in order to pass the result of `get` to `tell` in `performOp`. One important takeaway from this is that the relation is more to the specific `Writer` and `State` types, which happen to have `Monad` instances, than it is to the idea of monads. The reason I usually things like "the `Writer` type" instead of "the `Writer` monad" is that the `Monad` instance for those types are only one aspect to them. The other properties are very important and they are what make those types most related to this specific problem.

Really, the only time when something is very strongly connected to the particular concept of "monad" itself is when you have something that is polymorphic over all monads. For example, the builtin Haskell function [`filterM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:filterM) will work for *any* instance of `Monad`.

### A Haskell implementation

This is how it could be written using those types in Haskell:

```hs
sequenceOpsW :: [a -> a] -> WriterT [a] (State a) a
sequenceOpsW []     = get -- This branch shouldn't be reached unless it is explicitly passed an empty list
sequenceOpsW [f]    = performOp f
sequenceOpsW (f:fs) = do
  performOp f
  sequenceOpsW fs

performOp :: (a -> a) -> WriterT [a] (State a) a
performOp f = do
  x <- get
  tell [x] -- Update the Writer layer with the "old" value

  modify f -- Update the State layer with the new value
  get


sequenceOps :: [a -> a] -> a -> (a, [a])
sequenceOps fs x
  = flip evalState x
  . runWriterT
  $ sequenceOpsW fs
```

Your example could be run as:

```hs
addOne, mulTwo, subThree :: Int -> Int
addOne   = (+        1)
mulTwo   = (*        2)
subThree = (subtract 3)

exampleResult :: (Int, [Int])
exampleResult = sequenceOps [subThree, addOne, mulTwo, addOne] 10
```

If you want to understand this better, a good exercise would be to write your own (restricted) `Writer`/`State` combination type and make the appropriate `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` instances for it. The type would be something like this:

```hs
newtype StateWriter w a = StateWriter (a -> (a, w))
```

### A simpler, non-monadic way

However, unless we had a good reason to it this way, I'd rather write it directly without those datatypes or any monadic binds:

```hs
sequenceOps :: [a -> a] -> a -> (a, [a])
sequenceOps []     x = (x, [x])
sequenceOps (f:fs) x = fmap (x:) $ sequenceOps fs y
  where
    y = f x
```

(Here `fmap` behaves as though `fmap f (x, y) = (x, f y)` because we are using the `(,) r` `Functor` instance. I'm just using it for convenience, it doesn't have too much deeper significance to this application than that).

### Regarding Swift

I didn't write a direct Haskell translation of your `<<` because that kind of polymorphism works in a pretty different way in Haskell (you would need a type class and that brings its own issues with it).

I would personally suggest a Swift translation of the second implementation I gave over the first implementation. I wouldn't worry too much about using a pure implementation in Swift. The *interface* provided by the function is more important in my opinion and, regardless of how it's implemented, it will provide a pure interface. That's why the `ST` type works out well in Haskell. Also, I believe the `[]` type in Swift is an array, not a linked list, which would complicate a pure implementation and make it significantly less efficient.

Here's how I might approach it in Swift:

```
func sequenceOps<T>(fs : [T -> T], x : T) -> (T, [T]) {
    var result : [T] = []

    var curr = x

    for f in fs {
        result += [curr]
        curr = f(curr)
    }

    return (curr, result)
}
```

The implementation you provided in your question looks pretty reasonable to me as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply! I'll still need to use other sources to remind myself what Applicatives, etc. actually are before I can better understand it, but hopefully your answer will provide a good path of enquiry.

Comment: "The interface provided by the function is more important in my opinion and, regardless of how it's implemented, it will provide a pure interface." That's a very good point that had occurred to me too, and in fact the Swift implementation you suggested at the end was, for me (due to more imperative than functional programming experience), the "obvious" one. What I was doing here was really more of an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the different functions of the Haskell State Monad last night.
Even though generic type aliases would help there's not much code clutter involved.

Explanation: https://www.kohn.io/blog/2015/04/18/swift-state-monad/

Gist: https://gist.github.com/ankoh/533620a40c1e900e1082

You can copy&paste the Gist to your playground and just try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here the Swift 4 version of the same code, in case someone might want to try it out in a Playground:

```
precedencegroup WriterPrecedence {
    associativity: right
    higherThan: DefaultPrecedence
}
infix operator <<: WriterPrecedence
typealias Operator<T> = (T) -> T
typealias Accumulator<T> = (T, [T])
typealias Generator<T> = (T) -> Accumulator<T>

func wrap<T>(f: @escaping Operator<T>) -> Generator<T> {
    return { (x) in
        (f(x), [x]) }
}

func <<<T>(left: @escaping Operator<T>, right: @escaping Generator<T>) -> Generator<T> {
    return { (x) in
        let r = right(x)
        let lr0 = left(r.0)
        return (lr0, r.1 + [r.0]) }
}

func <<<T>(left: @escaping Operator<T>, right: @escaping Operator<T>) -> Generator<T> {
    return left << wrap(f: right)
}
```